# I need to fix the for loop to print the same shape on the example screen

Tags: c, for-loop

Basically i have a school task to make a C program that asks user for width input = n and makes the shape of a parallelogram/diamond.

```
Enter width: 4
   /\
  /  \
 /    \
/      \
\      /
 \    /
  \  /
   \/
```

This is my output:

```
Enter width: 4
    /
   / \
  /   \
 /     \
  \   /
   \ /
    \
```

This is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int n, i, j, l;

  printf("Enter width: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = i; j <= n; j++) {
      printf(" ");
    }
    for (l = 1; l <= 2 * i - 1; l++) {
      if (l == 1)
        printf("/");
      else if (l == (2 * i - 1))
        printf("\\");
      else
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n"); // novi red
  }
  for (i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    for (j = n; j >= i; j--) {
      printf(" ");
    }
    for (l = 1; l <= 2 * i - 1; l++) {
      if (l == 1)
        printf("/");
      else if (l == (2 * i - 1))
        printf("\\");
      else
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n"); // novi red
  }

  return 0;
}
```

But it does not print it like the one on the example output. I really tried to fix the problem but i just cant seem to make it work. I think the problem is somewhere in the second for loop just under the middle comment // novi red

Comment: [looks like you're very close](https://godbolt.org/z/14cjWEce3), just using the wrong type of slash for the bottom half. And no single slashes at the top and bottom.

Comment: @yano fixed the slashes, still cant fix it not being alligned

Comment: Add your current output up by the desired one.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError sorry what? I do not understand :D

Comment: You show the expected output at the top - if you add what your program produces now, we might have a better idea what the code error is.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Okay, added the output.

Comment: fixed it by myself

Answer (score 0):

Well, working and optimized code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printSpaces(int count);

int main() {
  int n;
  printf("Enter width: ");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    printSpaces(n-i);
    printf("/");
    printSpaces(2*i-2);
    printf("\\");
    printf("\n"); // new line
  }
  
  for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
    printSpaces(n-i);
    printf("\\");
    printSpaces(2*i-2);
    printf("/");
    printf("\n"); // new line
  }
 

  return 0;
}

void printSpaces(int count){
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        printf(" ");
    }
}
```

But don't just copy-paste it, read my explanation and tips, because you need to learn few things.

Firstly when you do something more times in your code, than extract that part of code to a function and than call it every time you need that code. This is the principle of functional programming and it makes your code much cleaner and save you a lot of time. In this case I created function to print spaces, because there were many for-loops just to print spaces.

The second main change I did in your code was your for-loop to print a line. I completely replaced it with my code and I will try to explain you why. When you think of your for-loop, it prints / at the first run, than prints spaces and at the end it prints one . And it doesn't really make sense when you do something only at the first run of the loop, because you can just write it before the loop and you get the same result. So instead of:

```
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
  if(i==0){
    //doSomething
  }else{
    //doSomethigElse
  }
}
```

Do:

```
//doSomething    
for(int i = 1; i<n; i++){
      //doSomethigElse
}
```

This is much more readable, logical and also faster.

So when I did this correction to your code, I end up with:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    printSpaces(n-i);
    printf("/");
    for (int j = 2; j <= 2 * i - 1; j++) {
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\\");
    printf("\n"); // new line
  }
```

And because now the for-loop is just printing spaces, I called my printSpaces function instead:

```
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    printSpaces(n-i);
    printf("/");
    printSpaces(2*i-2);
    printf("\\");
    printf("\n"); // new line
  }
```

But where was your mistake? Well, it was somewhere in the second condition of your if-else, but it doesn't matter that much. Much more important is to write clean and logical code, because than you can find errors and mistakes much more easily. Hope I helped you with your coding style.